# CodeIgniter link to search

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm completely new to PHP and CodeIgniter and I'm trying to create a link in a view that, when clicked will return a list of data from a specific category.

vgs_model.php model

```
public function pcList(){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('videogame');
    $this->db->where('Format', 'PC');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();

}
```

search.php controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');      
    $this->load->model('vgs_model');

}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('header_view');
    $this->load->view('search_view');
    $this->load->view('footer_view');
}

public function getPc(){

    $search_term = 'PC';

    $data['results'] = $this->Vgs_model->pcList();
    $this->load->view('search_results', $data);

}
```

search_view View

```
<a href = <?php echo site_url('Hello/getPc'); ?>>View PC Games</a>
```

I've been getting the following error

```
Message: Undefined property: Search::$Vgs_model

Filename: controllers/search.php

Line Number: 40
```

Line 40 is this
            `$data['results'] = $this->Vgs_model->pcList();`

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading my post.

Answer (score 1):

That sould be in lowercase:

```
 $data['results'] = $this->vgs_model->pcList();
```

Comment: Oh my god that is hilarious! Such a simple mistake. I love programming with a text editor. Thank you so much Charlie.

Comment: yeah, I do programming with text editor too, glad can help :)

Comment: Actually according to the CI conventions your model loading should be `$this->load->model('Vgs_model');` where the model name is capitalized. The above would then be kept capitalized unless you specify the 2nd parameter when loading to name it differently. See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html but that's just sticking to the way CI does it, which you should be using since it can have unintended side effects in latter releases.

Comment: Let's talk about should: That should not be an answer ;)

Comment: @hakre that should be wrong answer, I dont know anything yet about CI conventions, what is that? where to find them?

Comment: I was not commenting because of "wrong answer" but in the meaning that you could leave a comment instead IMHO and it should be sufficient and more useful for this website here.

Comment: mmm... I just read 'What am I doing wrong?' in the question, and I just answering 'That sould be...'